# Application Running With SSL not loading all scripts/CSS on first visit

Tags: javascript, .net, model-view-controller, ssl

Hopefully this isnt a tricky one. I've got a web app that doesn't load all javascript/css/images on **the first visit**. Second visit is fine.

After approximately **2 minutes of inactivity** the problem reoccurs.

These problems only started occuring **after** the customer requested SSL be applied to the application.

Ajax requests stop working after 2 minutes of activity despite a successful page load of all javascript elements.

Application timeout is 30 minutes - like I said, everything was fine before SSL was applied.

All javascript and CSS files use absolute URLS - e.g https://blablabla

There appears to be **no pattern** as to why certain files arent loaded. The firebug Net output shows the status for the failed elements as **'Aborted'**. For example, site.css and nav.css are in the same folder, are declared after each other in the head tag yet one is loaded and the other is not. Both will load fine after refreshing the page (unless roughly two minutes have passed).

An Ajax request also shows as aborted after two minutes. However, if i do the request again the Ajax request will **succeed**. Almost as if the first request woke something up.

**None of these problems occur in Chrome**

Any ideas? :)

FYI this is a .Net 4 C# MVC app running under IIS7 but I'm not sure its relevant since it works in Chrome. Everything worked fine before SSL was applied.

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue, not a developer or programming issue.

Comment: Try to ask this on serverfault.com with details of the SSl configuration used (and maybe debug of ssl if you can, or ask for help on that)

Comment: Wondering, do you start your visit from the http:// version of the website before jumping to https:// version. Secondly, isolate if this is a server or a browser issue -- directly visit the https:// versions of your CSS and JS and see if firebug complains about something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed SSL across the board and secured action methods with [RequireHttps]. Then changed the scripts and CSS in the master files to point to absolute HTTP urls. Javascript then worked fixing the ajax.

If anybody has any idea why CSS/Javascript broke over SSL it would be cool. Im guessing it's perhaps the work load? Since it worked the second time I'm guessing half the CSS and scripts were cached making less of a workload over SSL?

Anyway, working now!